# Violación de segmento (`core' generado) Python

Tags: python

Me encuentro cursando un tutorial de Biopython, y hay una sección donde se trabajan con secuencias, pero al ejecutar la siguiente linea:

```
>>> from Bio import SeqIO
```

Me da este error:

```
Violación de segmento (`core' generado)
```

Estuve investigando y parece que es algo con mis bibliotecas en C/C++ y mi versión de Python (3.8), instale unas bibliotecas zlib y reinstale mi versión de Python pero sigue sin funcionar
¿Alguien sabe por que ocurre esto? Gracias.

Comment: Buff..! Un error de violación de segmento es un bug serio, pero no está en tu código, sino en el de la biblioteca que estás tratando de importar. Es posible que se trate de un problema de dependencias (que las bibliotecas basadas en C que está usando no sean las que debe). Yo creo que la solución más sencilla es que instales Anaconda, que es una distribución de Python que te proporciona los binarios y bibliotecas específicos para tu plataforma, correctamente compilados. Y tiene Biopython.

Comment: También, si es para hacer pruebas rápidas, puedes usar Google Colaboratory, que es un entorno gratuito en el que poder ejecutar Jupyter Notebooks (código python interactivo organizado en una especie de libro). En su entorno de ejecución tienen ya muchas librerías numéricas importantes y las que no tienen las puedes instalar poniendo en la celda `!pip install BioPython` por ejemplo. Acabo de probar y se ha instalado con éxito. Y el `from Bio import SeqIO` se ejecutó correctamente sin _segfault_.

Comment: De acuerdo, tienes razón, use la herramienta Google Colab y funciono. Incluso probé en un servidor que tengo y también funciono. Sin embargo en mi equipo sigue sin funcionar, la verdad no se si es algo de mi equipo o una configuración de sw. Gracias